# Clean architecture/OOP and optimization: how to organize for classes with same logic

Tags: java, oop, clean-architecture

Let's guess I have class on server like

```
class MyData {
  String statusA;
  String statusB;
  String statusC;
  ...
  Something field20;

  boolean canDoX() {
    return statusA.equals('z') && statusB.equals('y')
  }
}
```

It is mapping from DB entity. Now for optimization was created new class

```
class MyDataWithHalfOfFields {
  String statusA;
  String statusB;
  String statusC;
  ...
  Something field10;
}
```

How should I replace `canDoX` so that it will be according to clean architecture?

Lang is Java but not really matter

**Update**

Why it is optimization. Designer wants 2 pages in frontend

1. Group of objects with data from array of MyDataWithHalfOfFields
2. Page of MyData

May be it won't be a big problem to get unnecessary fields for one object but for list it already more consuming

Answer (score 0):

I dont have xp with java, but i guess the question is more about oop than clean arch. But if java classes accept inheritance and abstract classes, or just inheritance, you can make a class with the specific behavior (canDoX()) an then extends in both classes. But, have a chance to use the MyData class instead MyDataWithHalfOfFields?

Comment: Yeah, I thought about inheritance, but there are other situations because of DB like "I need only update one field of object with id 'x'. I won't use Entity and update it in repository by field name" and I really don't know how to organize it to be readable and relatively save logic in one place. About "But, have a chance to use the MyData class instead MyDataWithHalfOfFields?" updated question

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing "cleaner" or "optimized" about the second class, it simply has fewer fields.

If you are writing a new app, and creating a new database alongside it, then remove unnecessary fields from the database.

If you are writing an app for an existing database, you may want to isolate your ORM/entity classes from the rest of your logic. Since you don't control the database, the ORM/entitiy classes are subject to change (several ORM libraries will create the classes for you from an existing database).

Either way, you should aim to have an ORM/Entity layer which strictly represents your data and has no other logic, then another layer which has translations or abstractions over the "raw" data (whether or not this is necessary depends on your app), then you should build your app logic based on the abstraction later (or the ORM/Entity if abstractions are not necessary).

Comment: That idea of having a strictly separate ORM layer usually means you transfer way more data than needed for the use case and then copy it around in memory multiple times in the worst case. Might be a clean architecture, but definitely not optimized.

Comment: @Voo it would probably depend on your app. Usually there are far better optimizations (algorithmic, or fixing memory leaks) than reducing the number of strings in a class (and we aren't really copying ORM classes around, usually). Optimization is usually a pass/fail concern on most of my projects (if it's good enough, don't waste time on it). Optimizing code at the expense of maintainability is ill-advised in all but the most performance-intensive applications, and usually one would not be using Java for those.

Comment: Reducing network IO (and worst case disk IO on the db side) is generally one of _the_ biggest optimization potentials and is after all exactly what the OP is asking about. But yes premature optimization and so on - for most apps performance is not a main consideration and even for the ones where it matters, it's usually a few important endpoints where you have to sacrifice architectural cleanliness for performance.

Comment: @Voo agree about db, but imo a little unclear what OP is asking about :)